# Create the English word for a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, numbers-to-words

I cobbled together a function from various sources that takes an integer and returns it as its respective English word formatted as a string. The function is as follows:

```
def int2word(num, separator="-"):
    """Transforms integers =< 999 into English words

    Parameters
    ----------
    num : int
    separator : str

    Returns
    -------
    words : str
    """
    ones_and_teens = {0: "Zero", 1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three',
                      4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven',
                      8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 10: 'Ten', 11: 'Eleven',
                      12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen',
                      15: 'Fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen',
                      18: 'Eighteen', 19: 'Nineteen'}
    twenty2ninety = {2: 'Twenty', 3: 'Thirty', 4: 'Forty', 5: 'Fifty',
                     6: 'Sixty', 7: 'Seventy', 8: 'Eighty', 9: 'Ninety', 0: ""}

    if 0 <= num < 19:
        return ones_and_teens[num]
    elif 20 <= num <= 99:
        tens, below_ten = divmod(num, 10)
        if below_ten > 0:
            words = twenty2ninety[tens] + separator + \
                ones_and_teens[below_ten].lower()
        else:
            words = twenty2ninety[tens]
        return words

    elif 100 <= num <= 999:
        hundreds, below_hundred = divmod(num, 100)
        tens, below_ten = divmod(below_hundred, 10)
        if below_hundred == 0:
            words = ones_and_teens[hundreds] + separator + "hundred"
        elif below_ten == 0:
            words = ones_and_teens[hundreds] + separator + \
                "hundred" + separator + twenty2ninety[tens].lower()
        else:
            if tens > 0:
                words = ones_and_teens[hundreds] + separator + "hundred" + separator + twenty2ninety[
                    tens].lower() + separator + ones_and_teens[below_ten].lower()
            else:
                words = ones_and_teens[
                    hundreds] + separator + "hundred" + separator + ones_and_teens[below_ten].lower()
        return words

    else:
        print("num out of range")
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### There's an easier way.

We have the `num2words` module which can be easily installed via `pip`:

```
pip install num2words
```

The advantage of this module is that it supports multiple languages:

> - en (English, default)
> - fr (French)
> - de (German)
> - es (Spanish)
> - lt (Lithuanian)
> - lv (Latvian)
> - en_GB (British English)
> - en_IN (Indian English)
> - no (Norwegian)
> - pl (Polish)
> - ru (Russian)
> - dk (Danish)
> - pt_BR (Brazilian Portuguese)

More, you can even generate ordinal numbers like *forty-second*.

A small python example for converting numbers to words using `num2words` looks like this:

```
>>> from num2words import num2words
>>> num2words(42)
forty-two
>>> num2words(42, ordinal=True)
forty-second
```

You can read more about what you can do using this module [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words)

---

*NOTE:* In case somebody is wondering why this is not a code review (such as comments on the posted code), is because in the unedited question the author specifically asked if there is already a library for this.

Comment: Well that is just cheating...    +1

Comment: Well, in the un-edited question the author specifically asked if there is already a library for this.

Comment: @ChatterOne IDK why that got edited out. Are we not supposed to ask about libraries here? So many rules :/

Answer (score 11):

You have quite a big bug there. In this part:

```
elif 100 <= num <= 999:
    hundreds, below_hundred = divmod(num, 100)
    tens, below_ten = divmod(below_hundred, 10)
```

If you have anything where the last two digits are less than 20, it's going to fail because the result is going to be `1` and 10 - that number (if you have `19`, you'll get `1` and `9`), which leads to a KeyError.

So, any number like `119`, `315`, `417` and so on will make it fail.
I'd say stick with the `num2words` that @Dex'ter suggested or be prepared to do quite some debugging.